# I have a question about URDF models and tf transformations

Tags: ros, urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I was convinced that if one defines, let's say 2 links, in a urdf file and joins them toghether with a joint element, then the physic relations between both links is going to be recognized automatically from tf when reading (parsing) the file at the moment to start the program. So it would be possible - I thought - to listen that transformation in my C++ program.

To make it clearer:
I have the following urdf file (of course it is just a barebone example)

```
  ##### base_link ##############################################################

  <link name="base_link">

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 ${offset_cg_ground}" rpy="${pi/2} 0.0 ${pi}"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://my_package/my_model.dae" 
              scale="${scale_factor} ${scale_factor} ${scale_factor}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="grey" >
        <color rgba="0.4 0.4 0.5 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>


 ##### base_frame ##############################################################

  <link name="base_frame">

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${cylinder_height}" radius="${cylinder_radius}" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    
    <!-- Inertial information is needed for Gazebo or simulation porpuses -->
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${mass}" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="${Ixx}" ixy="${Ixy}" ixz="${Ixz}" 
               iyy="${Iyy}" iyz="${Iyz}" 
               izz="${Izz}" />
    </inertial>

  </link>
```

which are assembled togheter with the following joint:

```
<joint name="base_link_2_base_frame" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_link" />
  <child link="base_frame" />
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 ${offset_cg_ground}" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
</joint>
```

Ok??
Now...in my C++ program I m going to broadcast only the transformation between the frames: `/odom` and `/base_link` . See the following snippet:

```
...
        odom_transform_.header.stamp    = ros::Time::now();
        odom_transform_.header.frame_id = "/odom";
        odom_transform_.child_frame_id  = "/base_link";

        ros::Rate loop( frequency_main_loop_ );

        do 
        {   
            /* Time must be always updated */
            odom_transform_.header.stamp    = ros::Time::now();

            /* Broadcast the position and orientation of the quadrotor */
            odom_transform_.transform.translation.x = actual_pose_.position.x;
            odom_transform_.transform.translation.y = actual_pose_.position.y;
            odom_transform_.transform.translation.z = actual_pose_.position.z;
            odom_transform_.transform.rotation        = actual_pose_.orientation;

            broadcaster_.sendTransform( odom_transform_ );

            ros::spinOnce();

            loop.sleep();

        } while( ros::ok() );
...
```

so no transformatiions between `/base_link` and `/base_frame` are going to be published in my program since I thought that those frames are fixed and their relative position is already configured in the urdf file.

Now...taking a look to the tf transformation printed in the pdf file I got confirmation that those frames are linked and recognized by tf, **BUT** I discovered that the command

```
rosrun tf tf_echo base_link base_frame
```

outputs the followings statements:

```
me@YE-166:~/workspace_ros$ rosrun tf tf_echo base_link base_frame
Failure at 254.547000000
Exception thrown:"base_frame" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. 
The current list of frames is:
Frame base_link exists with parent odom.

Failure at 254.547000000
Exception thrown:"base_frame" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. 
The current list of frames is:
Frame base_link exists with parent odom.

At time 256.020
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.084]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 257.020
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.084]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]

....
```

so it seems to me that at the beginning is the transformation not recognized. The robot move accordingly and i never suspected that I had such a problem in the tf tree. Would I never typed rosrun tf_echo... I would never discovered it.

If I had manually a tf::transformation direct in the code (like in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF))  I get no error message. But that's obvious since the transformation is now not given by the urdf file but from the code itself.

EDIT:
In my launch file I have the following robot_state_publisher:

```
<!-- Robot_state_publisher: needed for all the tf transformations -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" >
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="20" />
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />
</node>
```

The problem persists...
Anyway I would like to understand what is going on in my software.
Can you help me?

Thank in advance and
bye!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209134/i-have-a-question-about-urdf-models-and-tf-transformations/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_state_publisher expects the robot_description parameter to be in the global namespace, not a private parameter.

robot_description is set as a public parameter because it is used by multiple nodes, not just the robot state publisher.

Try this:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg urdf_file)" />
<!-- Robot_state_publisher: needed for all the tf transformations -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" >
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="20" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-05-13**:
Ok I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only way to get the transforms in a URDF to publish is by using robot_state_publisher.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2